# Javascript: Looping 2 asynchronized functions

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous

I have 2 asynchronized functions that need to alternate back and forth until a variable (activated inside of the function) calls them to stop. I've tried while loops but with the delay inside of the `playerTurn` function, the loop runs forever and overflows the program.

```js
var loopStatus = 1
playerTurn(author, "R", async function() {
  playerTurn(opponent, idTurn, async function() {
    playerTurn(author, "R", async function() {
      ...
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: that code pattern makes no sense... why are all the callback functions `async`? are you dealing with promises in that code

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Promise.race` it useful in such cases.

An example

```
const first = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one');
});

const second = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'two');
});

Promise.race([first, second]).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // Both resolve, but second is faster
});
```